# How to do MVC form url formatting?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, forms, rest, url-routing

I am using PHP. I want to create an MVC setup from scratch to learn more about how MVC works. I want to use clean urls with slashes as delimiters for the arguments. How do people do this when it comes to GET method forms? Or do people avoid GET method forms all together?

As of right now the ways I can imagine are:

1. Don't use GET method forms (although this makes it harder to let users bookmark/link in some cases).
2. Use AJAX instead of form submission (although what do you do for SEO and JS disablers?).
3. Have page submit to itself with post method, then reform the post vars into an url, then rerout to that url using headers (seems like wasted resources).

Any suggestions or suggested reading welcome.

Comment: seems there are many different oppinions on this.

Comment: https://www.taniarascia.com/the-simplest-php-router/ Helpful link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get variables and clean URLs don't contradict each other. You can always have URLs like

> http://example.com/controller/action?value1=foo&value2=bar

An alternative URL style could also look like

> http://example.com/controller/action/value1/foo/value2/bar
>   or
>   http://example.com/controller/action/foo/bar

In these 2 cases if you want to create these URLs via a form GET submit you will have to use JavaScript to assemble the correct URL therefore the very first solution might be easier to implement.

Another question is the decision between POST and GET form submission. POST is more secure but as you said, users can't bookmark it.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a `.htaccess` file like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

So... if the url is

http://example.com/controller/action/param1/

you can path the controller and the action, the index.php receive the var url [string]
and you can split them to load the controller...like

```
$params = explode('/', $_GET['url']);
$controller = new $params[0];//load the controller
$controller->$params[1]($params[2]);//ejecute the method, and pass the param
```

Answer (score 3):

As what i understand and my personal experience, none of your 3 points apply to how to handle a MVC Pattern:

1. thats a good and classy one about the subject http://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/whenToUseGet.html , basically, get is the way to go if the resulting URL coresponds with content, for an Example, don't use GET to pass information you want to save, don't use POST do transmit a ID of content you want to show the User. Its all about Url Patterns, and rewrites, you can probably draw some inspiration from the zend framework router http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html basically isn't `/?id=123` the same as `/weird-article-slug-123` when you know your URL Pattern is `^[\w\d-]+([\d]+)$`?
2. Nope, sorry, AJAX is at the very most, a way to use JS,so your AJAX Functions can only take advantage of your MVC Backend Application, the same way ... well, your "normal" HTML Interaction does.
3. That would be "wasted resources" indeed

Comment: I don't see an answer to my questiuon here?

Comment: @dqhendricks ok - basically ... using MVC on it self has just nothing to do with how you handle your urls - there are some best practices to how the 2 subjects get along but nothing more, and nothing less

Answer (score 2):

Cfreak the best way to answer this question would be for you digg into the various PHP frameworks source code to see how they've implemented an MVC approach. The PHP frameworks I've used typically exclude GET data and rely soly on POST data. However information can be passed via a query string see example below.

Typically URL's in PHP MVC frameworks look something like this: example.com/index.php/controller/action/arguments. The index.php part is usually removed by using an .htaccess file. You controller is a class, that most likely inherits from some sort of parent controller class. You controller has actions/methods whatever you prefer that are called next. You can pass these methods arguments, typically an unlimitied number of arguments by tacking them onto your URL. I hope that helps to give you a basic idea of the structure. Everything starts in index.php, which will include all your necessary config files, and load and required classes you may need :)

Answer (score 2):

What you're referring to with the URLs really has little to do with MVC. It is an implementation of REST architecture. ( [Wiki Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) )

Basically instead of using sessions, each URL should contain all of the information the server needs in order to create a request.

There are a couple of ways of doing this:

You can use Apache's mod_rewrite to rewrite a PATH to the proper GET parameters. For example say you have a user management module that is normally accessed with:

```
http://your.domain/users.php?request=edit&id=<some id>
```

You could put in Apache:

```
RewriteRule ^users\/edit\/(\d+) /users.php?request=edit&id=$1
```

Which would then allow you to address the same request with:

```
http://your.domain/users/edit/<some id>
```

(this is assuming ID is a number)

This is pretty easy to if all of the requests you expect to issue are pretty simple. If they are more dynamic then it gets harder to set it all up. The other drawback, if you were wanting to release your new framework, would be that it requires your user to have at least the ability to modify the Apache config through .htaccess files. That may not always be the case.

The alternative is write logic in the code that can parse the URL. In this case you usually need a controlling script for your entire site. The URL would be something like:

```
http://your.domain/users.php/edit/<some_id>

<?php

// get the part that appears after the script name
$parts = explode("/", $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] );

$request = $parts[1];
$id = $parts[2];

// do somethign with the $request and the $id 

?>
```

As you can see, my example is simplistic but with option 2, it's easier to put much more complex logic to do all sorts of things.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I know how to direct/use the clean urls how I want. The question is, how do you get a GET method form to submit as a clean url.

Comment: @dqhendricks - Redirect so it doesn't display. Rewrite it so it doesn't display or use POST. They can't "submit as a clean URL". The only thing you can do is hide it.

Comment: For my MVC I don't use $_GET variables in the common sense.  I simply pass them in as named paramaters.  So my URL looks something like this for "GET"-like variables: "www.site.com/controller/action/param1/named:param."  The colon is used to specify that the following value has a specific name.  I then set a global variable in my application to store all of the named variables.

Comment: This URL addresses resource naming in a RESTful API. I believe it should provide clarity to anyone who comes across it (who might be trying to create their own MVC system as per the question). Thank you for your answer @Cfreak . It put me in the right direction. http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/restfulresourcenaming.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in understanding how MVC frameworks / principles work sometimes the best way is first to understand how to implement them (something like CodeIgniter) you can then delve into the source code / documentation and understand how it works.

If you want to jump in at the deep end look into reading up on MOD_REWRITE to solve your URL concerns. GET is usable - you will just rewrite the URL components.

Comment: mod rewrite can direct clean urls to the true url, but how do you get GET method forms to go to (display) a clean url in the first place? Do you mod rewrite twice?

Comment: Do you mean instead of METHOD="GET" ACTION="?url=1&param=2" in the form code, METHOD="GET" ACTION="/url/1/param/2" ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this depends on what kind of page the resulting page will be.  If you are going to give the user a page with a single item on it, I would redirect them to that page, with a pretty URL.  That's not a huge demand on the system.

If I was going to show a list of results for a search query, I might well go for an unformatted GET query.  This, after all, could be a useful URL, which people might pass around:

```
http://www.example.com/search?name=lonesomeday&site=stackoverflow
```

On the other hand, if there was only one field, I might well redirect to a more simple form:

```
http://www.example.com/search/lonesomeday
```

YMMV, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about second approach - it's an horrible idea.

1. Usually you can use standard QueryString (`...?a=b&c=d`) in "GET forms" as their URLs aren't important.
2. However, if you really want to have nice URLs all the time you'll have to send a form (GET/POST - doesn't matter) and redirect user:

   ```
   if (/* form has been submitted */) {
       $data = array_map("urlencode", $_GET);
       $url = sprintf('/%s/%s/%s', $data['a'], $data['b'], $data['c']);

       header("Location: $url");
       echo "Redirection: <a href='$url'>$url</a>";
       exit;
   }
   ```
3. Eventually if you're worried about server resources you could use JavaScript to do that:

   ```
   formReference.addEventListener("submit", function() {
       /* do exactly the same as above PHP code */

       return false;
   }, false);
   ```

   Of course server-side redirection should be left in case somebody has disabled JS.

Answer (score 0):

The question you are basically asking is how to achieve SEO-friendly(Search Engine Optimization Friendly) URLs, in the format "www.site.com/controller/action/params".  This is achieved through editing your .htaccess file in a few key folders to redirect server to specified folders to gain a common access point for your web application, using MOD_REWRITE.  I would take a look at this [tutorial](http://anantgarg.com/2009/03/13/write-your-own-php-mvc-framework-part-1/).  The first few paragraphs explain how to achieve the URLs you are looking for.

Comment: I know how to use mod rewrite to direct clean urls to where I want them to go. The question was, how do you get GET method forms to go to clean urls in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Hey dqhendricks,
I am doing somewhat what you are doing -- learning MVC by studying other frameworks and creating one from scratch.

First of all, you shouldn't use GET to handle any form data. Use POST or PUT instead. POST is used only for retrieving information from web service. You can use actions in GET pretty much to manipulate what information to retrieve (e.g. sort order, page, etc).

Regarding your points:

**1) Don't use GET method forms**

Correct. It sounds incorrect in the first place that in order to get a certain view you have to use a form.

**2) Use AJAX instead of form submission**

Exactly. Your forms and URL's should work both with and without JS.

**3) Have page submit to itself with post method,** then reform the post vars into an url, then rerout to that url using headers (seems like wasted resources).

I would not say this is wasted resources. It will take only milliseconds for your app. In fact this is exactly what I end up doing. When front controller detects use of POST, it dispatches it to the Controller which performs necessary actions on submitted data. Based on result, app either redirects client, or renders requested page (no redirect). And yes, it works the same way for ANY URL.

At the same time, if a certain param was found in the URL, Front controller dispatches to respective controller. But this is never used to process data in any way. For example, this is used to remember preferred domain (www or mobile) when you want to use www when you browse in mobile browser.

Also, IMO you could say that wasted resources would be APP deciding where to redirect (or passing redirect URL in HTTP query or PHP session). In any case, it takes both development time and server resources to implement alternative methods.

So #3 is the way to go, in my opinion.