# beginner tutorial for .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to use .htaccess for my website, but I could not use it. I am unknown on how to use it. I have created .htaccess file.

I am trying to use my custom 404 error message (for now)

From [this](http://www.besthostratings.com/articles/change-error-documents.html) link I used

```
ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.html
```

But it did not work

Also from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4629543/604079) I tried things, but could not.

Can anyone walk me through?

What could be permission provided for the file

What is owner for the file.
Is there any setting to be set in any apache/php config file?

I am using Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this article about what configurations you have to make in httpd.conf, which is located in:

/etc/apache2/

LINK to article: http://chibimagic.wordpress.com/2009/02/27/apache-htaccess-mac-os-x/

then, you can jump into official apache doc for .htaccess: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: since i did not get answer for long, i figured it out already. configuring httpd.conf was the way to go. but forgot to mention in my post