# How to get file.php/dir header

Tags: php

I often see websites with URLs like `domain.com/index.php/directory`. How does it work? It looks like there is a directory in a file.

I want to do the same on my own website. Sample code is appreciated.

Comment: well you could just create a folder named 'index.php'

Comment: There is probably less magic than you think. My guess is that the URL is rewritten by the server.
Take a look on what url rewriting is https://aloneonahill.com/blog/url-rewriting-for-beginners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just create a folder named 'index.php' to achieve the same result, but I think what you are referring to is sites using Model-View-Controller (mvc) framework type.

I am not very familiar with the concept, but basically the file called is index.php and the following "directories" are in fact parameters passed to the script.

Maybe this could help: 
[How to do MVC form url formatting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627854/how-to-do-mvc-form-url-formatting)

Answer (score 0):

I think it has more to do with filesystems and less with PHP. A directory can be named `index.php` or any other thing with a dot.

Comment: Please use the comments section for suggestions. This is not a proper answer.